# Search in file using split

Tags: java, android, file

I have a users1.txt with some registries like: `basketball president tom@gmail.com 1234` and I am making the user to give as input the email,password and two choices of spinner , and I want to search them in the file and compare them , then if its true i will print a message (open() function). In the bellow code the condition was made with success but only for the first line of the file, I want to check all the file for each input of user. To be more specific , I want the search not to stop to `basketball president tom@gmail.com 1234` but continues to the second line `football referee tam@gmail.com 123123` etc. until the end of file. any suggestion would be great.

```
signBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {

                if( TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText()))
                    email.setError("Email Required");

               else if( TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText()))
                    password.setError("Password Required");

               else {


                   String text = readFromFile("users1.txt");
                        String[] splited = text.split("\\s+");


   if(SportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(splited[0]) && (UserSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(splited[1])) && (password.getText().toString().equals(splited[3])) && (email.getText().toString().equals(splited[2])))
         open(SportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), UserSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                      else
                      {
                          if(tries==1)
                              open();

                       signBtn.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);
                       tries--;
                       message(tries);
                      }

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private String readFromFile(String name){
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            File file = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),name);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("Exception", "File read failed: " + e.toString());
        }
        return String.valueOf(text);
    }
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips about how to debug your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines for the file are always in sets of the same number, you can use a loop to increment the indices that you check. I would also add a flag of some sort to stop searching if you found it.

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= splitted.length-3 && !found; i += 4) {
        if(SportSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(splited[i]) && (UserSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals(splited[i+1])) && (password.getText().toString().equals(splited[i+3])) && (email.getText().toString().equals(splited[i+2]))) {
        found = true;

        // Your open method goes here
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
    // Now put all the code from the previous else statement here, since it has now searched the whole list for the one set of inputs
    }
```

This checks every line of the file for a match and drops out of the loop if there is a match.